# How to store a number until next session?

Tags: xcode, integer, store, nsuserdefaults

How do I store a number, may be an integer, so it is back to use next session.
Suppose one can use NSUserdefaults is some way but don´t know how.
If I want to add a value to the already stored number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save Integer value like:

```
  NSUserDefaults *setObj = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [setObj setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100] forKey:@"Integer"];
  [setObj synchronize];
```

Get Integer value from `NSUserDefaults`

```
  NSUserDefaults *getObj = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  int Number = [((NSNumber*)[getObj objectForKey:@"Integer"]) intValue];
```

Comment: Thank you. Exact what I needed. Works ok.